# Shopify get parameters from home page

Tags: php, proxy, shopify

I'm beginner as `shopify` partner and I want to get parameters from home page using proxy app.

Url : mystore.myshopify.com/client_id=value

I want to get client_id via `shopify` app. What I have to do in path_prefix in proxy configuration.

Here more detail about what i want to get the parameters that I want with  proxy configuration and nothing received when visting home page\

parameters that I want:

[image: parametters that i want]

Proxy configuration:

[image: this configuration]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to provide more details than that

Comment: You know in shopify proxy you have /tools, /a, /community or /apps to get proxy client must visit /apps/... or /a/.... i want to get parametters from this url **https://tinywebstore.myshopify.com/?merchant_id=BR4QWJ58Z6CHP&employee_id=036S8SKSYKERP&client_id=9TTB5NM5Z4NCE&code=b3395ac2-19ae-1fe4-a715-2e39b4b86fd8** without visiting prefix-path. to resume @RST i want to get parametters from home page **/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

is to created a file Js in theme and send it via app proxy like what i do here.

`var client_id = getUrlParameter('client_id');
    jQuery(function($){

```
    /*  app proxy in jQuery*/            
    var base_urlc = window.location.hostname; //grab shop url
    var window_width = $(window).width();  //save width
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/apps/client",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: {client_id:client_id}
    })
    .done(function( msg ){
        console.log( msg );
    });

});`
```

Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

In your Partner setup of the proxy choose /tools, /a, /community or /apps and then some resource name. For example:

```
/apps/client
```

Set the URL to be your App's actual endpoint... https://foo.bar.com/yooba

Now you expect Shopify to send requests to your App's /yooba route.

Note that the JS you use will now be a GET or POST to /apps/client

Be careful with App Proxy. You can waste a lot of time with it. And note that the merchant can change the Proxy URL and break it anytime they want.

Comment: When i choose /apps as path-prefix or a/ client must visit /apps/... or /a/... to get proxy, to do that he must an admin of the store. **the question is**  how can i get parameters for home page **/** using shopify proxy without /tools, /a, /community or /apps

Comment: That is not true. You can access the proxy using a GET or POST from anywhere in the shop. You control the GET/POST using your code.